# Sharing code between C# and Script#: Script# Date class compatibility with C# DateTime

Tags: c#, script#

I have a lot of shared business logic code between C# projects and Script#.

Since the breaking change in script# core library (when DateTime class became Date) things gone south.

Has anyone come up with generic bulletproof solution how to handle it?
I read some people said they wrote a wrapper, but no one showed their sources.
There can be some pitfalls, like JS Date counting months from 0 and C# DateTime from 1
& so on, so it's not exactly trivial wrapper...

Forking the original script# and renaming Date back to DateTime is not really an option, since then you'll need to work on two project - yours and the fork.

References:

- [Issue 119 - DateTime class is missing in 0.7.4 Release](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/issues/119)
- [Issue 67 - Compile-time error with Nullable DateTime / user Enumeration.](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/issues/67)
- Script# - Release History: projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/ReleaseHistory

P.S.
    I'm aware of #ifdef solution, please don't suggest it ;)

Answer (score 0):

One potential approach is to store just the tick count as a long within your data model. Then use a set of helpers that interpret the ticks as a date/datetime and provide the APIs you're looking for. Just a thought... given the semantic differences, some wrapper/abstraction is anyway required for those who want to share code, and this is one approach for building that.

One side-benefit to this approach is serialization to/from json is simplified ... a) since there is no date literal syntax in JSON, and b) because the precision of ticks is different across script and .net ... so at the least if you use the .net tick count and it is not updated on the client, it just roundtrips without loosing precision.

If you do build this, this would be interesting to share back to the community.

Comment: This will require A LOT of changes in C#.    
As I understand you basically suggest just drop DateTime class usage at all.
   
What I want is to create DateTime class in Script# project, that will somehow proxy/wrap Date, so I won't need to change C# code and hopefully existing Script# code too, since the code base is rather large on both sides.


Than I will be able to use the latest version of Script#.